# async function returns correct value, but that value is undefined when chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm a bit new to async/await.  I can get my code to work if not chaining, but I'm trying to keep everything as modular as possible.  `readFiles()` is returning the correct value according to the log, but the "files" log is returning undefined.  Nothing breaks, but the ultimate value from `saveRecords()` is "undefined."

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {
  convertCurrencyStr,
  getFiles,
  getMsFromDate,
  parseJSON
} = require("./utils");

const saveResults = data => {
  const writePath = path.join(__dirname, "filteredRecords.json");
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(writePath, JSON.stringify(data));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not write data.", err);
  }
};

const filterRecords = data => {
  console.log("filtered", data);
  const deltaDateMs = getMsFromDate("January 1, 2016");
  try {
    const results = data.filter(item => {
      const registeredDateMs = getMsFromDate(item.registered);
      const afterJan16 = registeredDateMs > deltaDateMs;
      const isActive = item.isActive === true;
      const moreThan2000 = convertCurrencyStr(item.balance) > 2000;
      if (afterJan16 && isActive && moreThan2000) {
        return true;
      }
    });
    return results;
  } catch (err) {
    "No data available.", err;
  }
};

const readFiles = async () => {
  const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "data");
  try {
    const files = await getFiles(directoryPath);
    files.forEach(file => {
      const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, file);
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
      const results = parseJSON(data);
      return results;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not read files.", err);
  }
};

(async () => {
  const files = await readFiles();
  const records = await filterRecords(files);
  saveResults(records);
})();
```

Comment: Your `readFiles` function doesn't return anything. You probably want `map`, not `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Your readFiles need to have a return after the forEach, the return inside is for the array element you need another one to return the results.
And I am not sure if your filter will work, the if its not necessary, You should use only a

```
return (afterJan16 && isActive && moreThan2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your return outside the forEach

```
try {
    const files = await getFiles(directoryPath);
    let results;
    files.forEach(file => {
      const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, file);
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
      results = parseJSON(data);
    });
    return results;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Could not read files.", err);
  }
```